# Getting Django runserver dev logging to output via Grunt

Tags: django, gruntjs

I am (attempting) to learn to develop on Django, and coming from a Node background wanted to keep Grunt in my workflow. I use stylus and coffeescript, and use Grunt to watch and precompile the files for me, plus other small tasks.

To keep things compact, I had included grunt-shell-spawn, and was using it to run the server with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When I run this command from the command line by itself, I get full logging on requests, plus (more importantly) output from the `print` command. When I use grunt shell to handle this, the server loads and runs just fine, but I get no logging.

**If there a way to get grunt / python to output the dev logging, as normal, when running the server via grunt?**

THe full gruntfile for shell is:

```
shell: {
  django: {
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000',
    options: {
      stdout: true,
      async: true
    }
  }
},
```

and then I am calling it from concurrent as:

```
concurrent: {
  dev: {
    tasks: ['shell:django', 'watch'],
    options: {
      logConcurrentOutput: true
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, did you discover a solution for this? I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: just as a side note: `0.0.0.0:8000` can be shortened to `0:8000`

Comment: i'm trying to achieve the same thing and it only seems to log after i load the page. i don't see the output from just the manage.py runserver portion (where it says Validating models..etc) furthermore, i can't Ctrl + C in the terminal to kill the server once its started via Grunt. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you want this stuff, the **Django server logs** that lists HTTP requests and django logger reports. Example from our app:

> [02/19/2014 22:34:30] ERROR   : Details : [ Client ]: Mozilla [ Username ]: meanjim [ Id ]: 8278
>
> [19/Feb/2014 22:34:30] "POST /api/logcabin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16
>
> [19/Feb/2014 22:34:30] "GET /data/get_lesson_plan.json/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1366

So all you have to do is add the following attributes to the options object inside what you already have for shell:django.

```
options: {
    stdout: true,
    stdin: true,
    stderr: true
}
```

Happy bug hunting friend.

Comment: So you were half right. This DID add logging, but it required I also stop using concurrent. This module was overwriting the output (I guess). Once I just put mongo, django and watch into a task by themselves, it worked just fine. I am not sure concurrent was really going anything for me in this case anyways.

Comment: Interesting, I use concurrent with just the django runserver shell command and grunt:watch and nothing is being overwritten. I'll let you know if I come up with any thing better to improve this answer.